# Play Framework 1.2.4 Exporting/Importing project into Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have done a small project using Play Framework 1.2.4 and now I need to share it with my team members for further proceedings on that. I am using Eclipse Indigo for the project.

I tried exporting it into a WAR but when my team mates import it using the WAR option, they are getting lots of compilation errors.

Kindly let me know in which format should I share so that they don't get any compilation errors while importing it into their workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/ide):

> Play provides a command to simplify Eclipse configuration. To transform a Play application into a working Eclipse project, use the eclipsify command:

```
# play eclipsify myApp
```

> You then need to import the application into your Workspace with the File/Import/General/Existing project… menu.

Your coworkers should simply get the sources of the project, and run this command to generate an Eclipse project. You don't have to export anything. BTW, a war file is a deployable Java EE artefact. It's not meant to contain the sources of a Play framework project.

Side note: it's the second answer that I give you in a row that can be found in the documentation. Maybe you should read it.

Comment: Moving forward I will make sure on reading the documentation before posting :) For the first time when I create a new Play project, I used the eclipsify command to import it into Eclipse IDE. Then I worked on that and now I want to share this working project with my teammates which means I have to Export it from my Eclipse IDE, save it into some hard drive location and my team mates will import it from that location. In which format shall I export it then?

Comment: Why would you need to export it? The files are already there, on your hard disk. They should also be in your VCS. Your coworkers should get them from the VCS and run that command to generate the eclipse project. If you don't have a VCS, then definitely start using one. In the meantime, execute `play clean`, zip what you have on your hard drive, and send them the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of play the command is `play eclipse`

Then File -> Import.. -> Existing Projects into workspace

Don't check any boxes (ignore 'copy projects into workspace')

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, I agree with @JB Nizet and Connor.However this answer applies to old version of PLAY framework. My answer might be helpful for developers using Play Framework 2.3+ and come searching, the command to transform a Play application into a working Eclipse project.

- CD into your project source folder
- Run Activator eclipse projectName
- You are done ! Import the PLAY project as every other existing JAVA Project.